# How is collision entropy of German syntax higher than of English one?

Tags: syntax, entropy

As I explained in [the draft of my latest paper about linguistics](https://flatassembler.github.io/Karasica.doc), I have measured the collision entropies of English, German and Croatian syntax. The entropy of consonants in a long English text was log2(11), whereas, in an English spell-checking word-list, it was log2(13). Therefore, the entropy of the English syntax was log2(13)-log2(11). For German, the entropy of the syntax was log2(15)-log2(12). But log2(15)-log2(12)>log2(13)-log2(11). And, I hope we agree, English has a more complicated syntax, as English syntax is often requiring meaningless words such as "the", "that", "than", "it" (dummy pronoun)... So, how is this possible?

Comment: Make sure that your presuppositions on German and English syntax hold for the corpora you have chosen. Try other measures of syntactic complexity and look how they compare.

Comment: How exactly does German syntax not also require these exact same types of “meaningless words” (by which I assume you mean function words)?